# How to log all request to rails console in Mongoid 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

When using ActiveRecord one can see all SQL queries executed when page is being loaded. How to achieve the same with Mongoid 5?

Comment: For future visitors, if you want beautiful colored logging similar to active record, you might want to look at [the mongo beautiful logger gem](https://github.com/redline-gh/mongo_beautiful_logger/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can customize Mongoid logging level as [described in the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/#logging). You can also [configure it in the main Rails application](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/#id13).

```
module MyApplication
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.mongoid.logger = Logger.new($stdout, :warn)
  end
end
```

If you want to reuse the same Rails logger, simply assign `Rails.logger` (just make sure to assign it after the `Rails.logger` is initialized.

Comment: This was exactly what I did in the first place, but it doesn't work. I used `Logger.new($stdout, :debug)`

Comment: `Mongoid.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` worked for me in a console

Comment: neither works for me, still log goes to the file on rails 5